# How to print / echo environment variables?

Tags: bash, eval

How do I print the environment variable just being set?

```
NAME=sam echo "$NAME" # empty
```

You can see here using `eval` it works. Is this the way?

```
NAME=sam eval 'echo $NAME' # => sam
```

Comment: `NAME=sam echo whatever` does not change the value of `NAME` in the shell.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

These need to go as different commands e.g.:

```
NAME=sam; echo "$NAME"
NAME=sam && echo "$NAME"
```

The expansion `$NAME` to empty string is done by the shell earlier, before running `echo`, so at the time the `NAME` variable is passed to the `echo` command's environment, the expansion is already done (to null string).

To get the same result in one command:

```
NAME=sam printenv NAME
```

Comment: I added a note about `printenv`. Hope it's OK, @heemayl

Comment: Note that only the `printenv`-based command preserves the semantics of the OP's command: defining `NAME` as  a _command-scoped environment variable_, which only the invoked command and its child processes see, but no subsequent shell commands. The other commands do something very different: they define `NAME` as an _until-the-current-shell-exits shell-only variable_, which all subsequent _shell_ commands see, but _no external utilities_.

Answer (score 35):

To bring the existing answers together with an important clarification:

As stated, the problem with `NAME=sam echo "$NAME"` is that `$NAME` gets expanded by the current shell *before* assignment `NAME=sam` takes effect.

**Solutions that preserve the original semantics** (of the (ineffective) solution attempt `NAME=sam echo "$NAME"`):

Use either `eval`<sup>[1]</sup>
(as in the question itself), or `printenv` (as added by Aaron McDaid to [heemayl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40050822/45375)), or `bash -c` (from [Ljm Dullaart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40061017/45375)), in descending order of efficiency:

```
NAME=sam eval 'echo "$NAME"'  # use `eval` only if you fully control the command string
NAME=sam printenv NAME
NAME=sam bash -c 'echo "$NAME"'
```

<sup>`printenv` is not a POSIX utility, but it is available on both Linux and macOS/BSD.</sup>

What this style of invocation (`<var>=<name> cmd ...`) does is to define `NAME`:

- as an ***environment* variable**
- that is ***only defined for the command being invoked*.**

In other words: `NAME` only exists for the command (child process) being invoked, and *has no effect on the current shell* (if no variable named `NAME` existed before, there will be none after; a preexisting `NAME` variable remains unchanged).

POSIX defines the rules for this kind of invocation in its [Command Search and Execution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01) chapter.

---

**The following solutions work very differently** (quoted from [heemayl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40050822/45375)):

```
NAME=sam; echo "$NAME"
NAME=sam && echo "$NAME"
```

While they produce the same *output*, they instead define:

- **a *shell* variable `NAME`** (only) rather than an *environment* variable

  - if `echo` were a command that relied on *environment* variable `NAME`, it wouldn't be defined (or potentially defined differently from earlier).
- that ***lives on* after the command.**

Note that every environment variable is also exposed as a shell variable, but the inverse is not true: shell variables are only visible to the current shell and its subshells, but *not* to child processes, such as external utilities and (non-sourced) scripts (unless shell variables are designated as environment variables (too) with `export` or `declare -x`).

---

<sup>[1] Technically, `bash` is in violation of POSIX here (as is `zsh`): Since `eval` is a *special* shell built-in, the preceding `NAME=sam` assignment should cause the the variable `$NAME` to remain in scope after the command finishes, but that's not what happens.

However, when you run `bash` in POSIX compatibility mode, it *is* compliant.

`dash` and `ksh` are always compliant.

The exact rules are complicated, and some aspects are left up to the implementations to decide; again, see [Command Search and Execution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01).

Also, the usual disclaimer applies: [Use `eval` only on input you fully control or implicitly trust](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).</sup>

Answer (score 7):

This works too, with the semi-colon.

`NAME=sam; echo $NAME`

Answer (score 6):

The syntax

```
variable=value command
```

is often used to set an environment variables for a specific process. However, you must understand which process gets what variable and who interprets it. As an example, using two shells:

```
a=5
# variable expansion by the current shell:
a=3 bash -c "echo $a"
# variable expansion by the second shell:
a=3 bash -c 'echo $a'
```

The result will be 5 for the first echo and 3 for the second.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you can print with this command in your CLI
`C:\Users\dir\env | more`

You can view all environment variables set on your system with the env command. The list is long, so pipe the output through more to make it easier to read.