# runuser: why can't I echo variable that exists in printenv?

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to propagate the "inline" variable `TEST` into the `runuser` command below.

```console
$ TEST="hello" runuser -u user1 -- echo $TEST
$
```

The problem is, `echo $TEST` outputs nothing. But when I check using `printenv TEST`, the variable exists.

```console
$ TEST="hello" runuser -u user1 -- printenv TEST
  hello
$
```

My thinking is that, if `printenv TEST` sees the value `hello`, then so should `echo $TEST`. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Why is that? And how can I pass the `TEST` variable to the `runuser` command, without affecting the current shell environment? (That is, without doing `export TEST="hello"` nor `TEST="hello"; runuser [...]`.)

Comment: `$TEST` is expanded by the shell, before `runuser` and `echo` are even executed.

Comment: @Biffen in that case, then why doesn't `echo $TEST` output anything? By your remark, the command should have been expanded to `echo hello`.

Comment: No. `TEST="hello"` means set `$TEST` to `hello` _for the `runuser` process only_. What happens in your command is **1** the shell expands `$TEST` (to an empty string) **2** the shell executes `runuser` with `$TEST` set to `hello` **3** `runuser` executes `echo` with no arguments.

Comment: What you _could_ do is something like `TEST="hello" runuser -u user1 -- sh -c 'echo "$TEST"'`.

Comment: @Biffen I think I get it now, thanks for explaining! If my understanding is correct, this makes my post related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050793. My bad.

Comment: Yes, good find!